# How to solve npm ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT error when creating react app?

Tags: sockets, npm, create-react-app

I use npx create-react-app to boot strap my project. Installation process crashes with:

```sh
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fhelper-compilation-targets: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

I open that url with the Chrome browser and it works just fine:

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error.
The solution was to change the definition of the timeout.

It worked for me like a charm ✨

For changing the timeout,
Run these two commands:

`npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 20000`

`npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 120000`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

tnsaturday. Recently I also faced a similar problem as you. **I **solved this problem by simply uninstalling the latest node.js version which is 17.5.0 and installing 16.14.0 LTS.**** So, if you installed the latest version of the node then shift back to the previous version. I hope in this way you can solve your problem.

Comment: I use an nvm to manage node.js versions, so I'll definitely give it a try. Btw, try using the one yourself - it greatly reduces amount of hassle in the situation like this.

Comment: Sure, I would try this one thanks for the suggestion.